# Star-Comb Lemma

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification

I cannot understand that how can we apply Zorn's lemma here. What is the order set?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partially ordered set is the set of trees such that every edge lies on a path in that tree between two elements of $U$.  The ordering is by inclusion.  It satisfies the upper bound property because if we have a chain of such trees, we can take the union of their edges.  This is a tree because any loop is a finite collection of edges and those edges will all be in some member of the chain.  It is also clear that any edge lies on a path between two elements of $U$ ( that path being contained in the union ).  Therefore the union is an element of the partially ordered set and is clearly greater than ( ie. contains ) every element of the chain.  so the partially ordered set satisfies the conditions for Zorn's Lemma.